# Synchronous Call to NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, nsrunloop

I am writing a small Cocoa application for Mac OS, and my goal is to show a window, and then read the pixels on the screen. I already know how to do the latter part, but am having trouble with having the window show up before proceeding. From what I've seen, window updates like the ones triggered by NSWindow's makeKeyAndOrderFront are deferred.

I'm still relatively new to Cocoa, but I basically want to do something like this:

```
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
// application blocks right here until the window is actually shown
...
```

So how do I make that blocking operation happen?

Comment: Why not just show the window after you read the pixels? Neither should take that long.

Comment: I want to read pixels drawn by the window.

Comment: So you want to take a screenshot of one of your app's windows?

Comment: Yes, as part of an automated test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling -[NSWindow display] on your window, that will force it to display immediately.

Comment: Kevin also had a great suggestion of reading the window's pixels directly. You might consider using the -[NSView lockFocus] method and -[NSBitmapImageRep initWithFocusedViewRect:] to read directly from a specific window's backing store.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could obtain the pixels from the window, rather than the screen? On Mac OS X, (nearly) every window has its own buffer (backing store), whether or not it is visible. This will also ensure your test works even if there is a system dialog obscuring the area of the screen where the window is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delegate an object as the window's `NSWindowDelegate` and take your screenshot once `windowDidBecomeKey:` is called in the delegate.

Comment: I tried this, but was not getting the right results. It seems as though this callback is called just a little too early. For reference, I am drawing a rectangle that covers the entire screen.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?